# Difficult image arrangement

Tags: html, css, layout, grid-layout

I've got six images that need to be arranged in this specific layout.  I feel like I've been endlessly playing around with these but haven't gotten very far.  This is a WP project, so I'm using two ACF repeater fields.  Each repeater has three images.  I feel like I'm going about this all wrong and there is a much simpler solution than the route I'm going.  Anyone know how I can achieve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thank you!
[image]

```
<div class="container pt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                <div class="col-6 image-grid">

                    <!-- first row -->
                    <div class="row justify-content-between image-grid__row-first">
                        <?php if (have_rows('image_grid_row_first')) : while (have_rows('image_grid_row_first')) : the_row('image_grid_row_first');
                                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                        ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="">
                        <?php endwhile;
                        endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <!-- second-row -->
                    <div class="row justify-content-between image-grid__row-second">
                        <?php if (have_rows('image_grid_row_second')) : while (have_rows('image_grid_row_second')) : the_row('image_grid_row_second');
                                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                        ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="">
                        <?php endwhile;
                        endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the css:

```
.image-grid {
  img {
    max-width: 22.5%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: 50% 15%;
      outline: 12px solid white;
      height: 225px;
  }
  &__row-first {
    img {
      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        max-width: 55%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 260px;
      }
    }
  }
  &__row-second {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
    img {
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        max-width: 55%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual design to be? The picture you show has different proportions (widthwise) of the 3 images than the first row. I think first we need to understand more clearly what the design actually is.

Comment: Right, I think basically the smaller images for each row should be 25%, and the larger images be 50% to ensure they're responsive.

Comment: So there would be no overlap of the bigger pictures?

Comment: Not of the actual images, but top right image (with border/outline) will overlap the bottom left image - if that makes sense.   I just edited my original post and I think it's much better, but still I wonder if it's optimal.

Comment: Outline and border arent enough to get the sort of overlap shown. How about drawing say on graph paper what you want and then you can convert to grid columns and rows.